# How to get rid of Remix IDE "gas estimation" errors?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, remix

I am having with problems `PaymentSplitter.sol`. All is compiling well and deployed as expected. But every time I release(_address) on remix (button), I'm getting the following error:

> Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
> Internal JSON-RPC error. { “message”: “VM Exception while processing transaction: revert PaymentSplitter: account is not due payment”, “code”: -32000, “data”: { “stack”: "c: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert PaymentSplitter: account is not due payment\n at Function.c.fromResults …

I really don’t know what I am doing wrong… the only code I have included in my file is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import “https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/payment/PaymentSplitter.sol”;

contract MySplit is PaymentSplitter {
  constructor (address[] memory payees, uint256[] memory shares)
  PaymentSplitter(payees, shares)
  public payable{}
}
```

I keep on getting gas warnings and function loop warnings on remix every time I import `PaymentSplitter.sol` and have no idea what they trying to say.

Your help would be highly appreciated… Thank you

Comment: The `release` function is reverting because this assertion from the contract you imported is failing  `require(payment != 0, "PaymentSplitter: account is not due payment");`

Comment: So what should I do, because I didn't even edit the openzeppelin PaymentSplitter.sol code ? And one more thing, payment variable is always zero, I don't know why. Is there a bug ?

Comment: Well quite - that _is_ the problem : the function requires that  `payment` be non-zero. This is to do with the state of the deployed PaymentSplitter contract. It seems `payment` can be zero if either that account has no shares, or if that account has already released all their shares. In the first case, the function would have reverted with ""PaymentSplitter: account has no shares"" (line 105), so we know it's the second case.  It looks to me like everything is functioning correctly, just that your account already released its shares.